# Install R Shiny in a Computer that has no internet connection

Tags: r, installation, shiny, connection, cran

Hi I'm doing a government procedure which must be done on a brand new CPU, and I'm running a shiny app from zero and without internet connectivity. That means that I have to install R and RStudio from the very beginning and then run a shiny app all without an internet connection.

The trouble comes when I try to Run the Shiny app, because **In spite of having already downloaded and installed the shiny package from CRAN and have already locally installed it on the PC**, a pop-up box comes out saying:

*"Running Shiny applications requires updated version of the shiny package. Do you want to install shiny now? - YES - NO"*

Either option I choose doesn't seem to work, because If I choose "NO" the program just stop. And if I choose "YES" RStudio tries to connect to CRAN to download the Shiny package but it won't work because there is no internet connection.

Is there any way to install it successfully so I can run the Shiny App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! It was a little hard but finally got it. You have to do the following steps:

1. Get the newest version of R and RStudio. I used:

- R-4.0.5-win
- RStudio-1.4.1106

2. Download and Install locally the libraries listed [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nDBKdQpgOa8BxN3IiFHrohl1sPTG1nWD?usp=sharing).
3. Run as usual your shiny app.